# SQL: Why these queries are returning different results?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Why MAX is showing different than SUM?

```
SELECT name, price, MAX(downloads) FROM app_list GROUP BY price;
SELECT name, price, SUM (downloads) FROM app_list GROUP BY price;

    name    price   MAX(downloads)
    ABC     0.0     30000

    name    price   SUM(downloads)
    XYZ     0.0     1000500
```

In the second query, the XYZ app which is **free** has the total most downloads. Then how come app ABC which is also **free** is the most downloaded app?

Comment: I think `Group by` is the problem remove price and add name. Only Mysql allows to run this query. If possible add sample data

Comment: bet price for all the rows would be 0?

Comment: I suppose we should start with: Do you understand what `MAX()` and `SUM()` each do, and what the difference is between them?

Comment: I'm learning. I thought SUM calculates whole downloads in a column, where MAX calculates the most popular downloads.
But maybe MAX is the highest number of downloads at an unspecified row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a (mis)feature of MySQL, that simple should not be allowed.  In fact, the system parameter `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is the default in the latest versions.

What is the issue?  This is your first query:

```
SELECT name, price, MAX(downloads)
FROM app_list
GROUP BY price;
```

Whatever you might think or hope it is doing, the fact is that it returns an *indeterminate* `name` for each `price`.  The name has nothing to do with the maximum value.

If you want the maximum value, then use a subquery.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM app_list a
WHERE a.downloads = (SELECT MAX(a2.downloads) FROM app_list a2 WHERE a2.price = a.price);
```

This query also has the advantage that it can readily take advantage of a query on `app_list(price, downloads, name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why should id return the same values?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

> SUM() Return the sum
>
> MAX() Return the maximum value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make the `GROUP BY` by the name